# Potential Glide bug - RecyclerView item lose focus when fast scrolled with Dpad on Android TV

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, android-tv, d-pad

I am attempting to make a basic photo album app for Android TV.

Using recyclerview with glide.

**Issue**:
When scrolling one by one slowly by pressing dpad down button, recyclerview items gain focus accurately just as expected. But when dpad down button is kept pressed, during fast scroll, recyclerview item easily lose focus and the focus is moved to any focusable view (in this case an edit text) outside the recyclerview and no scrolling is possible until manually focus is moved inside recyclerview again.

**Remedies attempted**:
1. If I **disable image loading by Glide completely** (inside onBindViewHolder()), focus is never lost and no matter how fast the scrolling is it always works as expected. This remedy is not useful as images needs to be viewed.
2. If fast scrolling is limited by overriding Activity.onKeyDown method to ignore all key inputs unless 300ms has passed since last keydown it works. Again, this feels very hacky and completely disables fast scroll with is an absolute requirement.

Please note that I have already read the related QA on stackoverflow. Which suggested it's a bug in Android support library LayoutManager code which is not the case here since without glide it works fine.

**How to reproduce**: Create a fragment like ListFragment (code below) and try fast scrolling by keeping Down Dpad button pressed and you will see that editText constantly getting focused.

Code:
ListFragment.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;

import java.util.Random;


public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    RequestManager glide;

    public ListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        glide = Glide.with(this);


        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),8);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter();

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }







    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {


        private final String[] imageUrls = {"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2baa1821c67c1430401c65/1546365481213/20181208_0034pp2+810b2.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2baa218a922d1c5eb370c5/1546365483758/20181208_0115pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba92340ec9ab2ea3f0f73/1546365229886/20181215_0135pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba8880e2e72e38d92a482/1546365075745/20180914_0189+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba885f950b760dd6800a7/1546365086762/20180914_0168pp+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba9b1032be425c6948ca2/1546365375849/20180818_0014pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2baa184ae2379d323c4187/1546365481929/20181208_0065pp+810b2.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a256b9e4fcb574ae612941/1470258368357/20160801_0045.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a255d1e4fcb574ae61196f/1470256635728/20160717_0391.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a25695e4fcb574ae61273c/1470258368265/20160801_0040.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a256dbe4fcb574ae612b71/1470258369606/20160801_0108+pp+810+bw.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a257088419c29f345a7500/1470258369115/20160801_0108+pp+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba8e4f950b760dd6804fe/1546365168544/20181101_0067pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba83270a6adae0b3b6395/1546364992480/20181205_0164pp+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba8e4575d1f0c318f3727/1546365171139/20181101_0050pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a2543dd1758e06589e07f1/1470256544677/20160402_0075+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a253fad1758e06589e040f/1470256190368/20160402_0039+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a255fae4fcb574ae611e08/1470258367476/20160717_0444b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a2573be4fcb574ae613197/1470258370169/20160801_0123+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a257708419c29f345a7ba7/1470258369404/20160801_0272+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a25db19f74561d105005de/1470258684806/20160402_0046+810+nik2.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/55076c74e4b07b36ea118be0/1470413754677/20141222_0049.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a256688419c29f345a6b17/1470258368620/20160721_0097+pp2.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a255c9d1758e06589e1f5e/1470258367695/20160721_0012+ppb.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/56c21ac72b8dde5db5879498/1546363401197/20151107_0094+pp+57c.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/56c20eb662cd945cd5b485f5/1546363401197/20151024_1026+pp+810c.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/53558987e4b007661e339aa7/1470413754809/20140419_0430_pp1+5x7b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db7f3893fc0e1cdfe1bbb/1482536961660/20160507_0069b+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db8019de4bb91b69d5e37/1482537012182/20160904_0012+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db8346a496340ce2b8f6e/1482537056393/20160904_0043+pp+810l.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db846d482e9c87e69aa3c/1482537056630/20160904_0071+pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db860d2b857ddbd63c824/1482537071373/20160904_0119+pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db8602e69cf4bac703ff9/1482537081308/20160904_0124+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db8828419c2d595b13ee0/1482537109350/20161008_0086+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db8923e00be46604ad66c/1482537119283/20161105_0068pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db895b3db2b35c2346e97/1482537128208/20161128_0181+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db89fc534a5283f35edd0/1482537156287/20161203_0126+pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db8a703596eeb52691ac2/1482537145676/20161206_0101.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2baa1821c67c1430401c65/1546365481213/20181208_0034pp2+810b2.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2baa218a922d1c5eb370c5/1546365483758/20181208_0115pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba92340ec9ab2ea3f0f73/1546365229886/20181215_0135pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba8880e2e72e38d92a482/1546365075745/20180914_0189+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba885f950b760dd6800a7/1546365086762/20180914_0168pp+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba9b1032be425c6948ca2/1546365375849/20180818_0014pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2baa184ae2379d323c4187/1546365481929/20181208_0065pp+810b2.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a256b9e4fcb574ae612941/1470258368357/20160801_0045.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a255d1e4fcb574ae61196f/1470256635728/20160717_0391.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a25695e4fcb574ae61273c/1470258368265/20160801_0040.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a256dbe4fcb574ae612b71/1470258369606/20160801_0108+pp+810+bw.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a257088419c29f345a7500/1470258369115/20160801_0108+pp+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba8e4f950b760dd6804fe/1546365168544/20181101_0067pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba83270a6adae0b3b6395/1546364992480/20181205_0164pp+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/5c2ba8e4575d1f0c318f3727/1546365171139/20181101_0050pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a2543dd1758e06589e07f1/1470256544677/20160402_0075+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a253fad1758e06589e040f/1470256190368/20160402_0039+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a255fae4fcb574ae611e08/1470258367476/20160717_0444b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a2573be4fcb574ae613197/1470258370169/20160801_0123+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a257708419c29f345a7ba7/1470258369404/20160801_0272+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a25db19f74561d105005de/1470258684806/20160402_0046+810+nik2.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/55076c74e4b07b36ea118be0/1470413754677/20141222_0049.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a256688419c29f345a6b17/1470258368620/20160721_0097+pp2.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/57a255c9d1758e06589e1f5e/1470258367695/20160721_0012+ppb.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/56c21ac72b8dde5db5879498/1546363401197/20151107_0094+pp+57c.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/56c20eb662cd945cd5b485f5/1546363401197/20151024_1026+pp+810c.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/53558987e4b007661e339aa7/1470413754809/20140419_0430_pp1+5x7b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db7f3893fc0e1cdfe1bbb/1482536961660/20160507_0069b+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db8019de4bb91b69d5e37/1482537012182/20160904_0012+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db8346a496340ce2b8f6e/1482537056393/20160904_0043+pp+810l.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db846d482e9c87e69aa3c/1482537056630/20160904_0071+pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db860d2b857ddbd63c824/1482537071373/20160904_0119+pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db8602e69cf4bac703ff9/1482537081308/20160904_0124+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db8828419c2d595b13ee0/1482537109350/20161008_0086+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db8923e00be46604ad66c/1482537119283/20161105_0068pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db895b3db2b35c2346e97/1482537128208/20161128_0181+810.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db89fc534a5283f35edd0/1482537156287/20161203_0126+pp+810b.jpg","https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d6d61de4b03f5ac28c861a/55076abee4b038dc7dbd4f2a/585db8a703596eeb52691ac2/1482537145676/20161206_0101.jpg"};
        private final RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().centerCrop();
        private final Random random = new Random();
        private final Handler handler = new Handler();

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public ImageView icon;
            public View layout;

            ViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                layout = v;
                icon =  v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                       int viewType) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.getContext());

            View v =
                    inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view, parent, false);

            MyAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new MyAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }




        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            final String name = imageUrls[random.nextInt(imageUrls.length - 1)];


            //Commenting this out resolves focus loss
            glide.load(name).into(holder.icon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
            super.onViewRecycled(holder);
            glide.clear(holder.icon);
        }

        // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

    }
}
```

Layouts:
item_recycler_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:foreground="@drawable/fg_selectable"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="27:41"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
         />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ListFragment"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/editText"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve it? I'm pretty much in the exact same boat. I'm unable to "overwhelm" Leanback's ListRow even if i use Glide in the CardPresenter, but i can lose focus if i scroll the RecycleView really fast.

Comment: Same issue here. One thing I noticed is that once Glide has cached all the images the focus doesn't get lost any more. So a potential workaround is to pre-load and cache all the images.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a way to fix it? I did not try to use Picasso and see what's happening... I think is more of a layoutmanager or recyclerview bug than a Glide issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find any solution? I noticed that it's not only with Glide, but the same with Picasso. It's also only a problem when the images aren't cached, and are downloaded from URL (even without Picasso/Glide, just using regular download from URL to bitmap and then displaying it)

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need glide.clear() in onViewRecycled? My guess is that it has to do with frequent glide loading and clearing during fast scrolls. Glide may be getting somewhat confused. Also, why not Leanback Library and GridFragment? From my experience it works just fine with Glide and fast scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have removed the glide.clear() but it still results the same. I am not using the leanback because I also want to  support phones and tablets.